# Embed vs downloaded gif

Tags: download, embed, gif, animated-gif

I'd like to insert some GIF's on my blog but I have 2 questions that I can't find an answer:

1. Is it better to embed the GIF (with the code provided by Giphy for example) or to download it firt then upload on my web server? I mean, in terms of preformances, what's the best practice? The iframe loads so many stuffs... they might have an impact with the performances right?
2. Is it "legal" to download a GIF from Giphy and using it to my blog? I mean, instead of using their embed code. Does Giphy own some right on it?

Sorry if that question seems a bit dumb, but I never used any GIF before. So thanks for your understanding and for your answers :)

Comment: See also: [Is in-line linking (hot linking) photos and videos OK on my website, or is it unfair to the site which hosts them?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/91779/is-in-line-linking-hot-linking-photos-and-videos-ok-on-my-website-or-is-it-un)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is almost always better to download it to your site.  If you have a link to the image and the originating site deletes the file, you will end up with something other than you expect in that spot on your site.

As for whether it is legal, you would need to check the T&C of the Giphy site.